# Filtering groups in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2011

Ok, simple question to anyone who has experience with crystal (which I do not) ,
but I have a report that is pulling in open orders, items ordered, qty ordered, and qty on hand. I am grouping by order # and would like to filter out all the orders that have any items with insufficient qty on hand for any item on the order to ship. I tried a simple formula of {qty_on_ord} < {qty_on_hand} then {Ord_no}, and inserted this into the group header, but it didn't work. My end result basically wanted is: if an item has insufficient qty, then don't display the order at all, and could also go vice-versa and show the orders that are short, with a simple change of <>. Im sure this is simple, but I have no experience in crystal reports and have spent more time than I wanted searching the web.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to write the condition in supress part so that when condition matches data doesn't display

Answer (score 0):

Insert your formula at the Detail(Record) Level.
Go To Report > Selection Formulas > Record
There Enter your formula by selecting Fields from the "Report Fields"
This way you can just select the order Numbers you want and wont have to worry about the sum or totals at the bottom.